# Skip character from beginning of file

Tags: java, file-io

I am reading a file by character but I want to skip number of character from the beginning of file. For example this is the content of file:

**Hello. Read content by character**

```
 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

      int skipNumberOfCharacter = 12;
      char readCharacter;
      int ch;
      while ((ch = fis.read()) != -1) {
        readCharacter = (char) ch;
        System.out.print(readCharacter);
      }
```

When file process it should remove first 12 character from the content and should return out put as:

**content by character**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a skip method in  BufferedReader.

Probably you would like to have look at it.

[`BufferedReader#skip (long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#skip%28long%29)

Answer (score 2):

use `fis.skip(12);`

Or create a counter

```
int count = 12;
while (..) {
    count--;
    if (count > 0) continue;
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just do:

```
fis.read(new byte[12]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over `fis.read()` by `skipNumberOFCharacter`.

`for(int i = 0; i < skipNumberOfCharacter; i++) fis.read();`